# Is there a way to set Redis layer to existing Rails app in OpsWorks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, redis, aws-opsworks

I created a Rails app (2 layers) running in OpsWOrks (Ubuntu server) with MySQL data (1 layer).

Is there a way to create another layer for Redis and connected this Redis layer to the existing Rails layer(s)? I can create the Redis layer, but not sure how to connect them.

I've read there's a way to add Redis to the Rails layer with using Chef recipes, but I am not very familiar with Chef, so I am trying the layer-approach.

**EDIT:**

I tried to stop Redis, add this Redis layer under the "Rails" layer, but the result is still the same - I cannot verify that Redis is working.
If I log in to the server (for example on the `rails-myapp1` one) and run
[image]

> redis-cli

the output is

```
redis-cli
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/trusty-multiverse.list'

The program 'redis-cli' is currently not installed. To run 'redis-cli' please ask your administrator to install the package 'redis-tools'
```

Any tips how to figure out this?

**EDIT2:**

I had also the `redis1` layer under "Redis" (where is now "No instances"), but the result was the same.

**EDIT3:**

If I connected through SSH on the server where is Redis installed and run `redis-cli` and then `KEYS *` to see all what is cached by Redis, there's nothing.

In `config/environments/production.rb` is set

```
  #config.cache_store = :redis_store, "redis://localhost:6379/0/cache"
  config.cache_store = :redis_store, "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0/cache"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741359/how-to-run-redis-on-amazon-opsworks-for-a-rails-application

Answer (score 0):

OpsWorks doesn't provide built-in layer for Redis.

You can do something like [How to run Redis on Amazon OpsWorks for a Rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741359/how-to-run-redis-on-amazon-opsworks-for-a-rails-application) to use Elasticache and use custom cookbook to configure in your Rails instance.

Or if you want to create Redis instance in OpsWorks layer, you need to use custom cookbook to setup Redis server. After that you can use custom cookbook in Rails layer to find the Redis layer instance by using layer attributes:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/attributes-json-opsworks-layers.html . And then configure Redis into your Rails application.